# Permutation Question - Need help understanding the problem solving behind the question.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need help understanding part (c) of the question below.

---

A group of 5 boys and 5 girls line up outside a cinema. In how many ways can they be arranged:

(a) With no restriction?

(b) If a particular girl stands in line first?

(c) If they alternate between boys and girls (with either a girl or boy in first place)?

**Answers**:

(a) Since there are 10 unqiue people we do 10P10 = 10! = 3,628,800

(b) _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ----> There are 10 spots, but the first one on the left only has 1 possibility (the one girl that has to stand first), the other spots have 9! possibilities -----> $1\times9!$ = 362,880

(c) **I know how to get the answer, but I'm not quite sure why it works**. So again, you have 10 spots -------> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ,

Assume that we start with the girls first on the left-hand side, then there are 5 possibilities. The next has to be a boy and there are 5 boys left, so there are 5 possibilites. The next spot has to be a girl and there are 4 girls left, so there are 4 possibilities. And so on................... $\underline{5}\times\underline{5}\times\underline{4}\times\underline{4}\times\underline{3}\times\underline{3}\times\underline{2}\times\underline{2}\times\underline{1}\times\underline{1}=5!\times5!=14400$.

But you can replicate this exact scenario where the boys start first on the left-hand side and there will be the same amount of permutations. So you have $2(5!\times5!) = 28,800$ which is the correct answer. **But my method of solving it this way fails when there is an unequal amount of boys and girls. For example, what if you had 5 boys and 4 girls? How would you then solve that question? Can you suggest any other methods of solving this question?**

Comment: If there are $5$ boys and $4$ girls and if you want to arrange them alternatively, only possible option is first place should be occupied by boy... $BGBGBGBGB$ is fine.. You can not start with a gir you end up withl $GBGBGBGBB$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually quite limited there.

If there were $6$ boys and $4$ girls, it would be impossible to alternate genders.

In the case with with $5$ boys and $4$ girls, the girls have to be lined up between the boys, which means a boy is first and last. This would leave only $5!4!$ orders.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now, I wasn't thinking about the restrictions that would have to be made. Thanks.

Comment: There's a generalization though. You could say that the "minority" gender cannot stand next to each other. Let's say majority is A and minority is B. Then you would have $A! \times \binom{A-1}{B} \times B!$ this always works

Comment: doesn't work if A=B though. then just use your method

Comment: basically order all the majority gender people, choose B gaps within the A people (from A-1 gaps) and then order the B people within those gaps

Comment: I see. And if the number of majority gender was greater than 'The number of minority gender + 1' then there would be no possible permutations, right?. E.g. having 3 boys and 2 girls is fine, but 4 boys and 2 girls is impossible.

Comment: yes. if you must alternate genders then you can only have +1